# How to assign a value from the outcomes of Solve or 0?

Tags: equation-solving

Here is my problem:

I want to achieve a loop and assign the outcomes of Solve to variables for future use. But the equations in Solve may have no solutions. Under this circumstance, I want to assign 0 to my variable. But I don't know how to achieve it.

For example:

```
  solution = Solve[15 - 0.005 Qi^2 - (Qi Qj)/500 == 0 &&  10 - (3 Qi Qj)/2000 + 0.00025 Qj^2 == 0, {Qi, Qj}, Reals]
    x1 = solution[[1, 1, 2]]
    x2 = solution[[1, 2, 2]]
```

The outcomes of Solve under this pair of parameters are empty. So I want to assign 0 to x1,x2 but I don't know why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
solution =  Solve[15 - 0.005 Qi^2 - (Qi Qj)/500 == 0 && 
    10 - (3 Qi Qj)/2000 + 0.00025 Qj^2 == 0, {Qi, Qj}, Reals] // Quiet
```

> ```
>   {}
> ```

```
{x1, x2} = If[solution == {}, {0, 0}, {Qi, Qj} /. solution]
```

> ```
> {0, 0}
> ```

```
x1
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Alternatively,

```
solution2 =  Solve[15 - 0.005 Qi^2 - (Qi Qj)/500 == 0 && 
     10 - (3 Qi Qj)/2000 + 0.00025 Qj^2 == 0, {Qi, Qj},  Reals] /. 
  {} -> Thread[{Qi, Qj} -> 0] // Quiet
```

> ```
>   {Qi -> 0, Qj -> 0}
> ```

```
{x1, x2} = {Qi, Qj} /. solution2
```

> ```
>  {0, 0}
> ```

```
x1
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @lin my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.